# Cannot write GeoTIFF larger than 4GB with gdalwarp despite using BIGTIFF createopt

Tags: gdalwarp, vrt, bigtiff

I am running a Bash script to create a series of NetCDF grid files from MB-System that contain gridded swath multibeam bathymetry data. Each grid is unprojected Geographic Lat-Long, about 15-20MB in size. In the Lambert Conformal Conic projection I intend to use them in, the cell resolution would be 1m x 1m.

I merged all the files together using gdalbuildvrt:

```
gdalbuildvrt -overwrite mbgrids_merged.vrt *.grd
```

which ran fine and produced a VRT.

I then run gdalwarp on this VRT to project it to the projection I need it in and convert to GTiff for later import into GRASS:

```
gdalwarp -co "BIGTIFF=YES" -overwrite -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "$(g.proj -jf)" -tr ${RES} ${RES} -wm 30000000000 -r bilinear -multi -wo NUM_THREADS=14 -of "GTiff" mbgrids_merged.vrt mbgrids_merged.tif
```

(Note: I am in GRASS when I run this script, so the value of g.proj -jf is indeed populated)

This command produces the following error:

```
Creating output file that is 109731P x 19545L.
Processing mbgrids_merged.vrt [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. nan)
for image mbgrids_merged.vrt.
Copying nodata values from source mbgrids_merged.vrt to destination
mbgrids_merged.tif.
...10...20...30...40...ERROR 1: _tiffWriteProc:File too large
ERROR 1: TIFFAppendToStrip:Write error at scanline 2935
50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ERROR 1: mbgrids_merged.tif, band 1: An error occurred while writing a dirty
block from FlushCache
ERROR 1: _tiffWriteProc:File too large
ERROR 1: TIFFAppendToStrip:Write error at scanline 0
```

I understand that the merged tiff is going to be big, but that BIGTIFF createopt should have me covered, right? The created tiff size is exactly 4.0GB in size. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I am using gdal 3.7.2 and libtiff 4.1.0 on Linux Mint 20.3.

Comment: Your file could be too large to hold in memory. How much RAM do you have? You can try run it again while having htop open in a different terminal to see how much RAM is being used. htop - https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/htop

Comment: I have 64 GB of memory - I'll try your suggestion and report back, thanks.

Comment: I have no idea how large your tifs are so does the 32Gb run out while running gdalwarp by viewing it on htop?

Comment: I was wrong - I have 64GB of RAM, not 32. I'm re-running the script now.

Comment: The process crashes while only using about 29.5GB out of 64.

Comment: I am not sure how `-overwrite` works and if it knows something about the existing file. Try to write into a new file that does not exist. And for most use cases it is better to write a tiled tiff with `-co tiled=yes`

Comment: Try `gdalwarp` to another VRT instead of TIFF then `gdal_translate  -co "BIGTIFF=YES"`.  Also try reducing your warp memory size, 30GB chunks is too big.